# How to save data along with GeoFire location in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting, geofire

I'm developing an android app in which I would like to save the data with `GeoFire` location and then fetch it according to the location.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to save the data along with `GeoFire` location, though I'm able to save it using `.push().setValue()` method.

I actually have no code as I'm clueless how to do what I want.

Please let me know.

Sorry, if question seems badly formatted. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: Here I explained what worked for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62366763/2792809

Answer (score 0):

```
String key_of_data= ref.child("feeds").push(data).getKey();
```

Now the `key_of_data` variable contains the key of the feed data. So to save that data, the only option is to create a reference to this key with GeoFire. So `key_of_data` is given as the key for `geoFire`.

```
geoFire = new GeoFire(ref.child("user_location"));
geoFire.setLocation(key_of_data, new GeoLocation(lattitude, longitude));
```

This is how you save the data. For retrieving the data use the following code.

```
geoFire=newGeoFire(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users_location");
geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(geoLocation), 1);
geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
@Override
public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
    //key is the key to the feed data.
}
};
```

For more deatils, refer this Stack post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608281/storing-extra-data-under-geofire-nodes)